# $\frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{{x}^{a_1}}{1-x^{d_1}}+\cdots+\frac{{x}^{a_n}}{1-x^{d_n}}$ for all $x\neq 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

$\frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{{x}^{a_1}}{1-x^{d_1}}+\cdots+\frac{{x}^{a_n}}{1-x^{d_n}}$ for all $x\neq 1$.Then show that $d_1,\cdots,d_n$ cannot be all distinct.Also note that $a_1,\cdots,a_n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $d_1,\cdots,d_n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $ n\geq 2$.

Comment: So is $a_1=d_1=1$ or it follows any order

Comment: Not necessarily. they follow any order

Comment: The question is better stated as $\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\,\frac{x^{a_i}}{1-x^{d_i}}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|x|\neq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose without loss of generality that $d_1\leq d_2\leq \ldots \leq d_n$.  If the identity $\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\,\frac{x^{a_i}}{1-x^{d_i}}$ holds for all $x$ in an infinite subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (or for all $x\in S$ where $S\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is such that $|S|>\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\,d_i-n+1$ and $|S|>\underset{j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}{\max}\,\left(a_j-d_j+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\,d_i\right)-n+1$), then it is an identity over the ring $\mathbb{C}(x)$ of rational functions.  We claim that $d_{n-1}=d_n$.

Rewrite the identity as $$\left(\frac{x}{(1-x)}\right)\left(1-x^{d_n}\right)=x^{a_n}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\,\left(\frac{x^{a_i}}{1-x^{d_i}}\right)\left(1-x^{d_n}\right)\,.$$
If $d_{n-1}<d_n$, then substitute $x$ by $\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{d_n}\right)$, whence we have $0=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\text{i}a_n}{d_n}\right)\neq 0$, which is absurd.  Hence, $d_{n-1}=d_n$.